# EF Core global query filter based on nullable property resulting in NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, global-query-filter

I struggle to set up a global query filter in EF core.

I followed this example : [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cwith-constant#managing-state-in-pooled-contexts)

As in the example, I try to filter the data based on a TenantId property/column in the model/table. But unlike in the example, my application receives requests with tenant information (requests by a user) and requests without tenant information (requests by other applications).

My code:

```
public interface ITest
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<Int64>? GetTenants();
}

public class MyContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<MyContext> _pooledFactory;
    private readonly IReadOnlyCollection<Int64>? _allowedTenants;

    public MyContextFactory( IDbContextFactory<MyContext> pooledFactory, ITest tenant)
    {
        _pooledFactory = pooledFactory;
        _allowedTenants = tenant.GetTenants();
    }

    public MyContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        var context = _pooledFactory.CreateDbContext();
        context.AllowedTenants = _allowedTenants;
        return context;
    }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<SomeTable> SomeTable { get; set; } = null!;

    public MyContext( DbContextOptions<MyContext> options )
        : base( options )
    {
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Int64>? AllowedTenants { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating( ModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SomeTable>().HasQueryFilter( x => AllowedTenants == null || AllowedTenants.Contains( x.TenantId ) );
    }
}
```

`AllowedTenants` contains the ids of the tenants to which a user has access. `AllowedTenants` is null if no filter should be applied.

The filter works if `AllowedTenants` is not null.
But when it is null, I get the following exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.<VisitIn>g__ProcessInExpressionValues|29_0(SqlExpression valuesExpression, Boolean extractNullValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.VisitIn(InExpression inExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean& nullable)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SqlExpression sqlExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean preserveColumnNullabilityInformation, Boolean& nullable)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.VisitSqlBinary(SqlBinaryExpression sqlBinaryExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean& nullable)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SqlExpression sqlExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean preserveColumnNullabilityInformation, Boolean& nullable)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SqlExpression sqlExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean& nullable)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SelectExpression selectExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(TableExpressionBase tableExpressionBase)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(TableExpressionBase tableExpressionBase)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SelectExpression selectExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(TableExpressionBase tableExpressionBase)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(TableExpressionBase tableExpressionBase)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SelectExpression selectExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Process(SelectExpression selectExpression, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean& canCache)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalParameterBasedSqlProcessor.Optimize(SelectExpression selectExpression, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parametersValues, Boolean& canCache)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerParameterBasedSqlProcessor.Optimize(SelectExpression selectExpression, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parametersValues, Boolean& canCache)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalCommandCache.GetRelationalCommandTemplate(IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.RelationCommandCacheExtensions.RentAndPopulateRelationalCommand(RelationalCommandCache relationalCommandCache, RelationalQueryContext queryContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.<<PopulateSplitIncludeCollectionAsync>g__InitializeReaderAsync|63_0>d`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass33_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteImplementationAsync>d__34`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteImplementationAsync>d__34`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__33`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.<PopulateSplitIncludeCollectionAsync>d__63`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.<TaskAwaiter>d__69.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNextAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.<SingleAsync>d__14`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.<SingleAsync>d__14`1.MoveNext()
```

Is there a way to make something like this work?
I know about `IgnoreQueryFilters` but that is not an option for me.

Comment: What if you make AllowedTenants an empty collection instead of null?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks for the suggestion. That works. But I still don't understand why the version with null + null check does not work. It almost feels like EF translates the expression in a way that the second condition gets evaluated even if the first one result to true.

Comment: I don't either, but you can create an issue for it if you want. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues

Comment: Beyond the scope of this question, but I would absolutely not allow requests without any tenant filter in a multi-tenant application. The risk of accidentally exposing one tenant's information to another is too great. If you need to report on cross-tenant questions, I'd do that from a replicated reporting database with separate access control.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the full filter you passed in at `OnModelCreating` has to be translatable to SQL. That includes both sides of your OR condition, because these expressions are supposed to be evaluated in the database.

So, when `AllowedTenants` is null, EF will try to construct an 'IN' statement while looping around your collection, causing a null reference exception.

Initializing this collection instead of setting it to null would be the way to resolve this and then checking its item count to be zero as your first condition.